# Installing Windows 8 on vmware 6.5

Tags: windows-8, vmware-workstation

Is there any way to install Windows 8 on a VMWare Workstation 6.5.

I can't install it, get this message:

> The installation failed with this error "vcpu-0:NOT_IMPLEMENTED vmcore/vmm/intr/apic.c

---

I found this link

http://www.sharepointsolutioncenter.net/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=46

It says don't try it but just in case anyone has done it please tell. I don't want to download vmware workstation 8 or 9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need VMWare 8 or 9 as 6.5 is not compatible with Windows 8.

Source - [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_cp-windows_install/how-do-you-install-windows-8-into-vmware/a3ec3602-8ccc-4194-bc7c-25a5c4b41ddc)

Answer (score 2):

You need VMware 8 or greater, as mentioned [here](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1826897#1826897)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to above error is to download and install [Virtual Box 4.1](http://www.mytricks.in/2011/09/guide-install-windows-8-developer.html) on your machine and deploy Windows 8 Virtual Machine on top of it.

Windows 8 System Requirements:

> 1 Gigahertz (GHz) or faster 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64) processor
>   1 Gigabyte (GB) RAM (32-bit) or 2 GB RAM (64-bit)
>   16 GB available hard disk space (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)
>   DirectX 9 graphics device with WDDM 1.0 or higher driver

Comment: Why are you suggesting a preview version of Windows 8? Considering the preview likely already expired, this answer, is less then helpful.  Would be easier just to deploy Windows 8.

Comment: i correct that.